# routerCanReuse and routerOnReuse is not called when route changes

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to figure out the OnReuse and CanReuse parts of Angular2's Router and I'm hitting a wall. I modeled my code after the docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html), but for some reason I can't get the methods to call when the route changes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Location, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {ProductTable} from './product-table.component';
import {AddProduct} from './add-product.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'ProductTable', component: ProductTable, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/add-product', name: 'AddProduct', component: AddProduct }
])
@View({
    templateUrl: __resourcePath + '/html/app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
})
export class AppComponent {

    public __resourcePath = __resourcePath;

    constructor(public location: Location) {

    }

}
```

product-table.component.ts

```
import {Component, NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {CanReuse, OnReuse, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';
import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-table',
    templateUrl: __resourcePath + '/html/product-list.html',
    directives: [NgClass]
})
export class ProductTable implements CanReuse, OnReuse {

    public storeProducts: Store_Product__c[] = [];
    public selectedStore: string;
    public selectedCategory: string;
    public errors: { [id: string]: string } = {};


    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {

    }

    routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('routerCanReuse fired');
        return true;
    }

    routerOnReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('Reusing!');
        console.log(next);
        this.selectedStore = next.params['selectedStore'];
        this.selectedCategory = next.params['selectedCategory'];
        this.storeProducts = next.params['storeProducts'];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add `NgClass` to Directives. `NgClass` is globally available by default as part of [COMMON_DIRECTIVES](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/COMMON_DIRECTIVES-let.html)

Comment: Can you please confirm, that you don't get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no errors whatsoever

Comment: `@View({` was removed recently. What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Just realized I'm on 2.0.0-beta.3. I'm updating and refactoring for a minute

Comment: This discussion might be helpful https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7784#issuecomment-202492405

Answer (score 1):

I think the docs are not clear enough, or we just looked up a wrong doc.

Angular will not consider a component is resusable if router navigates to a component of different type. The following explanation is extracted from Angular's [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2f581ffc88466138675b3fa13b8c44d328439e68/modules/angular2/src/router/directives/router_outlet.ts#L79)

> [router-outlet's reuse method is ]Called by the {@link Router} during recognition phase of a navigation.
>                                                                                                  If the new child component has a **different Type** than the existing
>   child component, this will resolve to `false`. You can't reuse an old
>   component when the new component is of a different Type.
>                                                                                                  Otherwise, this method delegates to the child component's
>   `routerCanReuse` hook if it exists, or resolves to true if the hook is
>   not present.

It is likely that you never navigate from `ProductTable` to `ProductTable`. So `CanReuse` hook is never called. But you can try reusing strategy in components like `ProductDetail` where you will navigate from one item's detail to the next item's detail.

Comment: See also [router-outlet's doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterOutlet-directive.html), it seems equally confusing

Comment: So the way things sit right now it's impossible to do this with 2 different components?

Comment: Maybe this can be done by DynamicComponentLoader. But I have no idea.